# How do I get Japan tourist visa?

Tags: visas, transit, japan, indian-citizens

I am an Indian holding US green card and want to stay in Japan for 3-4 days on my way to India from the USA. What are the requirements?

Comment: Have you tried to get information from the Japanese government?  See http://www.us.emb-japan.go.jp/english/html/travel_and_visa/travel_and_visa_index.htm.

Comment: Also note that generally residence in another country doesn't change visa requirements, only your country of citizenship

Answer (score 3):

You want to apply for a Tourist/short term visa from the Japanese embassy.

The requirements would be based on your country of citizenship/passport, i.e. India. As such, this is a summary of what is required for you to apply (The following information is assuming you are applying from the US) -

> **Required Documents**
>
> - Applicant's valid passport
> - "VISA APPLICATION FORM TO ENTER JAPAN"
> - One recent photograph (2" x 2")
> - Proof of sufficient funds to defray all the expenses while in
>     Japan
> - Flight itinerary issued by travel agency or airline company.
> - Documents indicating the purpose of your visit
>
>   - If you are visiting
>       relatives/friends, an invitation letter from a relative/friend
>   - If you
>       are traveling for business, a letter from the inviting company in
>       Japan and a letter from your company
>   - If you are participating in a
>       conference, printed material on the conference
>   - If you are
>       sightseeing, information regarding places you plan to visit,
>       confirmation of hotel reservation, etc.
> - Immigration documents showing
>     your legal status and permitting reentry into the U.S., such as
>     permanent residency (green) card or I-94 and valid U.S. visa.
>
>   - If you do not intend to return to the U.S., visa to next the destination (if required) must be affixed to your passport before you apply for Japanese visa.

Source: http://www.us.emb-japan.go.jp/english/html/travel_and_visa/visa/short-term-visit-tourist.html

If you are applying from India, refer to http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/short_term%20visas.html

Comment: Since OP is presumably living in the US, he will need to apply at the Japanese embassy in the US, which may have different requirements than the one in India.

Comment: @fkraiem And indeed it does: http://www.us.emb-japan.go.jp/english/html/travel_and_visa/visa/short-term-visit.html